# Interpreting results of lsblk and df commands

Tags: mount, partition, disk-usage, fdisk, unmounting

I am having a hard time interpreting the results of the below commands.  The more I read about them the more I'm convinced that what I am seeing is somehow not what it's supposed to be.

1. The results of the `df` command show that `/dev/sda1` is mounted on `/` (as it should be), but why do the results of `lsblk` list that the mount point of `sdb1` is `/`?
2. Should both drives be flagged as boot drive in the results of fdisk?

   ```
   michaele@data-node-3:~$ df
   Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
   udev             7690624       8   7690616   1% /dev
   tmpfs            1540136     340   1539796   1% /run
   /dev/sda1       10287416 1373528   8373280  15% /
   none                   4       0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
   none                5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
   none             7700676       0   7700676   0% /run/shm
   none              102400       0    102400   0% /run/user

   michael@data-node-3:~$ lsblk
   NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
   sda      8:0    0   100G  0 disk 
   └─sda1   8:1    0   100G  0 part 
   sdb      8:16   0   250G  0 disk 
   └─sdb1   8:17   0    10G  0 part /

   michael@data-node-3:~$ sudo fdisk -l
   Disk /dev/sdb: 268.4 GB, 268435456000 bytes
   4 heads, 32 sectors/track, 4096000 cylinders, total 524288000 sectors
   Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
   Disk identifier: 0x0009626f
      Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
   /dev/sdb1   *        2048    20971519    10484736   83  Linux
   Disk /dev/sda: 107.4 GB, 107374182400 bytes
   4 heads, 32 sectors/track, 1638400 cylinders, total 209715200 sectors
   Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
   Disk identifier: 0x0009626f
      Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
   /dev/sda1   *        2048   209715199   104856576   83  Linux
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lsblk` gets the mountpoint information from `/proc`, but you could show the results here using the `mount` command.

However, with the provided information, the entries for `/dev` and `/run` look like the place where `/dev/sdb1` is used: that's 10G, and `/dev` and `/run` normally do not have a lot of diskspace used.  Seeing the output of `mount` would help understand why `lsblk` reported `/dev/sdb1` as "/".

Your root filesystem "/" is consistent with `/dev/sda1` according to `df`, and (unless you setup a multiboot system), only one partition should be marked "boot".